# how to hide selenium browser prompt in python?

Tags: python, selenium, prompt

I made a python crawling program
I made a exe.file by pyinstaller this program

everything's fine but one problem.
actually it's not a problem just I don't wanna see it.

when I click start button prompt window pops up in exe file.
but when I click start btn in pycharm , it doesn't appear.

how can I hide this prompt window?

I made exe file with pyinstaller 
and that code is

`"pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --add-binary "C:\chromedriver.exe";"." GUI_tabbed.py"`

and the prompt looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDNMc.png)

i tried -w , --noconsole , -windowed ... etc ...

I'm tired of searching it.

help me.

Comment: `--noconsole , -windowed ... etc` define the behaviour of your exe, but dont care about other modules that might start some processes via `os.system` or `subprocess` (like the selenium module has to launch a new browser window).

Comment: thank you  Solved